# How to make android apps of low size?

Tags: android, eclipse, size

I was doing a little project thing for my school...

I made a simple calculator app...with simple mathematics operations...
And when the apk file is created and installed, it was consuming the memory space of more than 700 kb in the phone.
While in the android market(play store), there are just similar apps which are of low sizes and are taking memory space of less than 500. I was creating app in eclipse...

Will somebody plz help me out with this that how they do make apps of simple lower size.??

Comment: Do you have lots of images or use large third party libraries?

Comment: We don't know what you have put in your app. Post details for relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest APK I created is ~35kB. Size increases dramatically with the included assets. Check the size of your /res, /assets and, if you have it, /raw folders. The APK size will be larger than those three combined. Further, any included lib counts, and adds bulk, even (and especially) the compatibility library, if you use it.

Comment: Are there any extra(useless) files in the android project which i can remove without any problem?

Comment: That really depends on your project. If you started with the skeleton project (Eclipse/File/New Android Project), and simply extended it, then nothing in there is superfluous. The Java compiler will drop unused code, though. Your best bet is still to look at your assets and see what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having lot of graphic assets, then you should probably look at using [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). They save a lot of memory.

Answer (score -2):

Please elaborate your question. When you say memory, are you referring to the RAM OR the actual storage memory ?

If you are referring to storage memory...

- The storage memory depends on how big your application is. For e.g. IF you have too many images of large size, then app size will increase.

By the way,  700K is not really too much. You are OK.